# Printing Attribute Values in python-amara

Tags: python, xml-parsing, amara

I'm trying to parse an xml file with using python-amara.

```
doc = amara.parse('h.xml')

assert doc.xml_type == tree.entity.xml_type
m = doc.xml_children[0]

print m
```

When I do this it gives

```
amara.tree.element at 0x94c864c: name u'HOP', 0 namespaces, 0 attributes, 93 children
```

However when I try this :

```
print doc.HOP.A.D
```

it says:

```
AttributeError: 'amara.tree.entity' object has no attribute 'HOP'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To access elements in a way you are trying to do it, you must use

```
from amara import bindery
doc = bindery.parse('h.xml')
```

instead of

```
doc = amara.parse('h.xml')
```